# Creating build Variables for azure devops build pipeline from external file through Terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating Azure devops build pipeline through terraform and want my build variables to get passed through an external file while the build gets created. The same terraform code will be used to create pipelines of different templates, so accordingly the variables will also change, so inorder to make it reusable for all pipelines i want my terraform codes to take the build pipelines variables from external file and create it. Can't go with variable groups as well. So if any other process please advice.
Any help or advice would be really appreciated.

```
resource "azuredevops_build_definition" "build" {
  project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
  name       = "Sample Build Definition"
  path       = "\\ExampleFolder"

  ci_trigger {
    use_yaml = true
  }

variable {
    name  = "PipelineVariable"
    value = "Go Microsoft!"
  }

  variable {
    name      = "PipelineSecret"
    secret_value     = "ZGV2cw"
    is_secret = true
  }
```

the variables that above passed should instead get passed from external file.

Comment: Why can't you specify the variable values on the command line or via different `.tfvars` files?

Comment: This terraform code will be part of a bash script to create end to end infra, so the plan is to pass the build variables through an external file and variables might vary from requirement to requirement basis, so using directly an external file

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define terraform variables for the values you require and use them in the resource:

`variable "buildinfo"{ type = string default = "my value" }`

and in the resource you just use:

`.... value = var.buildinfo ....`

you can pass the variable value for each run with a tfvars file or in your pipeline variables if you use a CI

Answer (score -1):

you could do it like this:

Terraform:

```
variable "PipelineVariable"" {
}
```

Then define variables in the Pipeline like `TF_VAR_PipelineVariable` or in any stage you call a file (example file: .env) with `source .env`:

.env:

```
export TF_VAR_PipelineVariable=CONTENT
```